# How do I restrict MediaWiki user groups from access to portions of my wiki by namespace?

Tags: mediawiki

In the release notes of Mediawiki 1.18 there is this line:

$wgGroupPermissions now supports per namespace permissions.

I cannot find the implementation within the documentation. The wiki page for $wgGroupPermissions has not yet been updated to handle this change.

I wish to put copyrighted material up that will only be accessible to a certain class of users while leaving the rest of the wiki open.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a very hard time parsing what exactly occurred here (wikimedia's infamous bureaucracy).. but what it looks like to me is that the release note made it in ([diff](https://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/tags/REL1_18_0/phase3/RELEASE-NOTES-1.18?r1=101933&r2=101936)), but the [change to actually enable the feature](https://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/User.php?r1=91931&r2=92364) was reverted.

The only clear notes on this seem to be in the [commit notes for the revert](https://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki?view=revision&revision=105851), with nothing in the [outstanding bug](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14801).

> Reverted r92364 (per-namespace permissions).
>
> This is the wrong configuration format for such a feature, and the wrong interface. We already have certain per-namespace permissions in the Title class, and we didn't need to add extra formal parameters to a whole lot of User methods in order to get them. The feature should be implemented wholly in Title, and the concept of user rights should remain relatively simple and easy to understand, and independent of its many applications, i.e. a user either has a right or doesn't. Rights are just a tool for developing access policies; the complexity should be in the caller.

Comment: Well, chalk up several wasted hours of upgrade time for naught. I'll stop looking and holding my breath then and start looking into this Title class. The big reason I pushed up to 1.18 was to be able to close off one namespace. Oh well.